# OData with LINQ how to specify a navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I want LINQ to generate precisely this URI:

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(xcenter=1M,ycenter=1M)/Results
```

Where `xcenter` and `ycenter` specify my key and `Results` is a navigation property of the OData service that contains the data I want.  If I type in this URI to the browser I get the results I want.

I can *almost* get LINQ to generate this, but I cannot get it to do the /Results part on the end. So if I do:

```
var query = context.MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters
                   .Where(t => (t.xcenter == 1 && t.ycenter == 1))
                   .Select(t => t);
```

I get the URI like this:

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(xcenter=1M,ycenter=1M)
```

That's a start, now I just need to specify the navigation parameter.  I did try this:

```
var query2 = context2.MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters
                   .Where(t => (t.xcenter == 1 && t.ycenter == 1))
                   .Select(t => new { t.Results });
```

However, the URI it generated looks like this:

```
http://<webservice>/MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters(xcenter=1M,ycenter=1M)?$expand=Results&$select=Results
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642489/why-wouldnt-my-odata-service-entity-framework-allow-navigation-properties) that the above URI is supposed to be the same as `/Results` but for my particular service I'm dealing with it does not work, I need my generated URI to be precisely as I wrote up at the start with `/Results` on the end.

Does anyone know how I can get LINQ to do this?

Comment: what is the value of context? And why linq of a string? I would rather use regular expressions on this

Answer (score 0):

Try `SelectMany` i.e

```
var query2 = context2.MULTI_POINT_PARAMParameters
               .Where(t => (t.xcenter == 1 && t.ycenter == 1))
               .SelectMany(t => t.Results);
```

Use `SelectMany` for collection navigation properties and `Select` for single navigation properties.